# how to insert a newline \n after x numbers of words, with AWK or Sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have this in one line:

```
We were born in the earth beyond the land
```

I want it in 3 words lines, to be like this:

```
We were born
in the earth 
beyond the land
```

Comment: Can you showed the code you've tried for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ xargs -n3 < file
We were born
in the earth
beyond the land

$ egrep -o '\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+' file 
We were born
in the earth
beyond the land
```

Comment: Well, xargs seems so obvious _now_ :-)

Comment: Really clever use of xargs -n! Would've never thought of that, was going the awk route.

Comment: This gave me some issues when working with transcripts involving ad-hoc use of the apostrophe: xargs tries to match them in pairs; treats the contents of a pair as a single argument; doesn't insert newlines in such contents; and also removes the apostrophes. I overcame this by explicitly specifying a space as delimiter via `-d' '`. So `xargs -d' ' -n3 < file` allows me to handle: "We were born in t' earth beyond t' land". (Using `-0` didn't work btw.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ 
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
        printf "%s%c", $i, (i % 3 == 0) ? ORS : OFS 
    } 
}' infile
```

It yields:

```
We were born
in the earth
beyond the land
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\(\w\w*\W*\w\w*\W*\w\w*\W*\)/\1\n/g' input
```

and short version:

```
sed 's/\(\(\w\w*\W*\)\{3\}\)/\1\n/g' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/\s/\n/3;s/\s/\n/6;s/\s/\n/9'
```

It replaces the third, sixth and ninth spaces with newlines.

This one will handle longer lines, even if they aren't multiples of three words:

```
sed -e 's/\(\(\S\{1,\}\s*\)\{3\}\)/\1\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Any system that has awk and sed will almost certainly also have Perl:

```
 cat myfile.txt | perl -lane 'while(($a,$b,$c) = splice(@F,0,3)){print "$a $b $c"}'
```

Comment: I'd say AUUoCA - Almost UUoCA... its use is that I find this conceptually easier to comprehend, because I read from left to right I like thinking about my data flow in the same direction.  Also this maintains 1 arg per command so there's never any confusion about correct ordering of args.